# Nested ajax calls theory

Tags: ajax, nested

I've found many questions regarding users that requires to execute nested ajax call, but I can't understand if it is a good choice or not to nest them.

Most people tell to "divide" in multiple functions, for example:

```
function firstCall() {
    $.ajax({
        // [...]
        onSuccess: function(response){
            secondCall();
        }
    });
}

function secondCall() {
    $.ajax({
        // [...]
        onSuccess: function(response){
            thirdCall();
        }
    });
}

function thirdCall() {
    $.ajax({
        // [...]
        onSuccess: function(response){
            andSoOn();
        }
    });
}
```

1. Is this the only solution?
2. What are the main problems of nested ajax calls?

I'm developing a web application that requires a lot of ajax interation and sometimes I have to nest the ajax calls, for example to retrieve data that depends on first ajax call result in order to refresh DOM elements

3. Should I move everything to the back-end?

Comment: If the results of each`ajax` call depends on the previous, using callbacks is *unavoidable*. There are more modern ways to perform callbacks in a structure by using `Promises`, but callbacks work just fine too.

Comment: I'll have a look at [promises.js](https://www.promisejs.org/) thanks @NickZ

Comment: Promises are native in JavaScript now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the only solution?

No, there is another way to handle `ajax` requests similar to this by using [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), but functionality wise it is still the same as using callbacks.

> What are the main problems of nested ajax calls?

Main downsides that I can think of with nested `ajax` calls is that if one call fails, it might interrupt the rest of the successive `ajax` calls, so this may create issues if not accounted for.

Comment: It will interrupt for sure the rest of the calls, but since they depends on the result of the previous in most of the cases, this is not a great problem, since it would be handled with the `onError()` callback... With *problems* I mean something like "the second call start before the first call finish rendering the result or modify the DOM elements required for the second call"

Comment: If you call the next 'ajax' method once the previous has finished, something like that should not happen.